# The type or namespace "Toolkit" does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft.MixedReality" with MRTK3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

So I made a new Unity Project with the MXTK3 and Unity Version 2021.3.6f1 (LTS). My goal is to track an QR Code, show a small Window with Data (What URL does the CR Code Contain) and then a Button to open the Link in the Endge Browser with the HoloLens 2.
Sadly I can't access CameraCache as I can't import the Toolkit because I got the following error:

> Assets\Scripts\SpatialGraphNodeTracker.cs(2,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Toolkit' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.MixedReality' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I used the Tool to install following Packages from MRTK3:

- MRTK Core Definitions
- MRTK Graphic Tools
- MRTK Input
- MRTK Spatial Manipulation
- MRTK Standard Assets
- MRTK UX Components
- MRTK UX Core Scripts

Beside that just The one XR Thing from Plattform. Any ideas what I can try?

[VS shows the packages but not the imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY1dC.png)

Comment: Seems like my VS Project does not have a reference to the Toolkit Projects. No Idea how I fix that tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got my solution from here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-removes-project-reference-to-packages.1324617/#post-8374734

> If your code is in a .asmdef assembly, you have to locate the asmdef
> file for QRCodeSample and set the appropriate references in its
> Inspector view. Seeing as you get a VS project for
> Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Core, that assembly seems to be a
> .asmdef assembly itself (as opposed to precompiled), which means you
> should add that asmdef in the "Assembly Definition References" section
> of your .asmdef Inspector.
>
> If your code is just going to Assembly-CSharp or similar, then you're
> going to want to either modify the package itself to mark the asmdef
> for Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Core "Auto Referenced" or add a
> .asmdef for your code and set up the required asmdef references
> yourself.

Thanks again to cyriaca